# Actionscript 2: Function won't run

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I define a function and try and run it but it won't run, if i take the code out of the function it runs fine and I can't work out why, here is the function and the call...

```
function Boomclat() { 
        var TweenX:Tween = new Tween(this, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, this._x, 16.9, 1, true);
        var TweenY:Tween = new Tween(this, "_y", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, this._y, listY, 1, true);
        }
        Boomclat();
```

Here is my whole code (on this MC, there is more outside):

```
    onClipEvent (load) {
    import mx.transitions.Tween;
    import mx.transitions.easing.*;
    startX = this._x;
    startY = this._y;
    mn = 0;
}
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
    this.onRollOver = function() {
        this.gotoAndStop("over");
    };
    this.onRollOut = function() {
        this.gotoAndStop("up");
    };
    this.onPress = function() {
        this.gotoAndStop("down");
    };
    this.onReleaseOutside = function() {
        this.gotoAndStop("up");
    };
    this.onRelease = function() {
        this.gotoAndStop("up");
        this.enabled = false;
        this.arrow.gotoAndStop("ordered");
        if (_global.hasAnswered != 1) {
            this.arrow.listNumber = this._parent.Order.length+1;
            listY = 35+(74.9*this._parent.Order.length);
            this._parent.Order.push(this);
            function Boomclat() { 
            var TweenX:Tween = new Tween(this, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, this._x, 16.9, 1, true);
            var TweenY:Tween = new Tween(this, "_y", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, this._y, listY, 1, true);
            };
            Boomclat();
            this._parent.buttonHolder.previousOrder.push(this);
        } else {
            for (i=0; i<this._parent.trueOrder.length; i++) {
                if (this == this._parent.trueOrder[i]) {
                    _global.previousButton.enabled = true;
                    _global.previousButton.gotoAndStop("up");
                    myColor = new Color(_global.previousButton);
                    myColor.setTint(255,255,255,0);
                    myColor = new Color(this);
                    myColor.setTint(113,205,0,23);
                    this.gotoAndStop("down");
                    var TweenX:Tween = new Tween(_global.lastText, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Back.easeOut, 276.4, -210, 0.7, true);
                    _global.whichText = this._parent.textFile[i];
                    var TweenX:Tween = new Tween(_global.whichText, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Back.easeOut, 760, 276.4, 0.7, true);
                    _global.lastText = whichText;
                    _global.previousButton = this;
                }
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Anyone can see what's wrong? Cheers.

Comment: This is not an answer, but I don't think you should have the definitions for onRelease and so on in the enterFrame event. You only need to run that code ones, enterFrame will execute repeatedly lots of times (for example 24 times a second at 24 fps).

Comment: True, thought they needed to run continous to recognise rollovers etc, obviously not cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough if I define the function before the onRelease it works... here is final code:

```
onClipEvent (load) {
    import mx.transitions.Tween;
    import mx.transitions.easing.*;

    function orderTween() {
        var TweenX:Tween = new Tween(this, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, this._x, 16.9, 1, true);
        var TweenY:Tween = new Tween(this, "_y", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, this._y, listY, 1, true);
    }
    startX = this._x;
    startY = this._y;
    this.onRollOver = function() {
        this.gotoAndStop("over");
    };
    this.onRollOut = function() {
        this.gotoAndStop("up");
    };
    this.onPress = function() {
        this.gotoAndStop("down");
    };
    this.onReleaseOutside = function() {
        this.gotoAndStop("up");
    };
    this.onRelease = function() {
        this.gotoAndStop("up");
        this.enabled = false;
        this.arrow.gotoAndStop("ordered");
        if (_global.hasAnswered != 1) {
            this.arrow.listNumber = this._parent.Order.length+1;
            listY = 35+(74.9*this._parent.Order.length);
            this._parent.Order.push(this);
            orderTween();
            this._parent.buttonHolder.previousOrder.push(this);
        } else {
            for (i=0; i<this._parent.trueOrder.length; i++) {
                if (this == this._parent.trueOrder[i]) {
                    _global.previousButton.enabled = true;
                    _global.previousButton.gotoAndStop("up");
                    myColor = new Color(_global.previousButton);
                    myColor.setTint(255,255,255,0);
                    myColor = new Color(this);
                    myColor.setTint(113,205,0,23);
                    this.gotoAndStop("down");
                    var TweenX:Tween = new Tween(_global.lastText, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Back.easeOut, 276.4, -210, 0.7, true);
                    _global.whichText = this._parent.textFile[i];
                    var TweenX:Tween = new Tween(_global.whichText, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Back.easeOut, 760, 276.4, 0.7, true);
                    _global.lastText = whichText;
                    _global.previousButton = this;
                }
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: As Lars stated below you have a scoping issue Plus the fact that you are defining the mouse events inside of the onClipEvent along with the import statements. You need to pull those functions out of the onClipEvent function. The code you posted is not quality code(sorry for being blunt). ActionScript 2 can be very tricky with scoping and the "this" keyword. "this" can refer to many things depending on where it is being used. I would suggest you do some google searching on the "delegate" method and learn it well if you plan on staying with ActionScript 2.

Comment: Do some reading. http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/205/1/The-Delegate-Class/Page1.html

Comment: It was not scoping, the function plain wouldn't run. a simple trace statement inside the function wouldnt fire. How would you take the import out of the onclipevent? Statement must appear within on/onclipevent handler. It works fine as shown above.

Comment: read up on exactly what onClipEvent is. http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary614.html

Comment: By putting the functions definitions inside the onClipEvent you are recreating the function every frame event. This is why you have to put it last, is because if you put it before the orderTween() function it is not created yet and as such does not exist since the function scope is local to the onClipEvent function.

Comment: Functions created inside another function are scoped to the function they will not have global scope. I also edited my answer for you with removing the onCLipEvent, since there is absolutely no reason for you to be defining your functions inside of it.

Comment: its onclipevent load, it runs on load. enterframe would run continuously this does not. The scoping is a valid point but I use the same function in a different movie with an onrelease function and it works so I don't think this is it. But it works fine now, thanks for taking an interest in this.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common causes of errors in AS2 is scope issues. Maybe the `this` keyword doesn't reference the object you intended in the Boomclat function. You could add a trace call, `trace(this)`, in the function, to see if it is the object you wanted to tween or not.

**Edit**: I see now that Boomclat is defined inside another function, the onRelease handler. I'm not sure you can do it with that exact syntax. If you want nested functions, one way to do it is like this, storing the function reference in a local variable:

```
var boomclat:Function = function () { 
   var TweenX:Tween = new Tween(this, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, this._x, 16.9, 1, true);
   var TweenY:Tween = new Tween(this, "_y", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, this._y, listY, 1, true);
};
boomclat();
```

Or you could define the function elsewhere, outside of the onRelease handler, and instead only call it from the onRelease handler.

But given the code you posted, I would say you could just as well execute the code inline, I don't really see why you would need the function there.

Comment: It works fine without the tweens outside of a function, and the function simply isn't running I can put `trace("hello")` into the function and it does not output so the function never runs.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looping the Boomclat() function?
Clearly the tween effect will not be finished and probably won't even be started before you trigger the tween again in essence resetting the tween
[EDIT]
Opps, for some reason I thought the function call was inside the function.

Anyway, have you verified the variables are accessible inside the function.

```
function Boomclat() { 
  trace( this._x )
  trace( this._y _ )
  trace( listY )
  var TweenX:Tween = new Tween(this, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, this._x, 16.9, 1, true);
  var TweenY:Tween = new Tween(this, "_y", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, this._y, listY, 1, true);
}
Boomclat();
```

[EDIT2]

```
//remove the  onClipEvent completely and you should be ok
    import mx.transitions.Tween;
    import mx.transitions.easing.*;

    startX = this._x;
    startY = this._y;
    this.onRollOver = function() {
        this.gotoAndStop("over");
    };
    this.onRollOut = function() {
        this.gotoAndStop("up");
    };
    this.onPress = function() {
        this.gotoAndStop("down");
    };
    this.onReleaseOutside = function() {
        this.gotoAndStop("up");
    };


// you might have to fix the references to this._parent to get it target what you want.
    this.onRelease = function() {
        this.gotoAndStop("up");
        this.enabled = false;
        this.arrow.gotoAndStop("ordered");
        if (_global.hasAnswered != 1) {
            this.arrow.listNumber = this._parent.Order.length+1;
            listY = 35+(74.9*this._parent.Order.length);
            this._parent.Order.push(this);
            orderTween();
            this._parent.buttonHolder.previousOrder.push(this);
        } else {
            for (i=0; i<this._parent.trueOrder.length; i++) {
                if (this == this._parent.trueOrder[i]) {
                    _global.previousButton.enabled = true;
                    _global.previousButton.gotoAndStop("up");
                    myColor = new Color(_global.previousButton);
                    myColor.setTint(255,255,255,0);
                    myColor = new Color(this);
                    myColor.setTint(113,205,0,23);
                    this.gotoAndStop("down");
                    var TweenX:Tween = new Tween(_global.lastText, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Back.easeOut, 276.4, -210, 0.7, true);
                    _global.whichText = this._parent.textFile[i];
                    var TweenX:Tween = new Tween(_global.whichText, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Back.easeOut, 760, 276.4, 0.7, true);
                    _global.lastText = whichText;
                    _global.previousButton = this;
                }
            }
        }
    };

// as you can see I put it last
    function orderTween() {
        var TweenX:Tween = new Tween(this, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, this._x, 16.9, 1, true);
        var TweenY:Tween = new Tween(this, "_y", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, this._y, listY, 1, true);
    }
```